# Wordpress form to add hotels

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a webpage to add hotels (database for hotels) using wordpress. (name, address, pictures, reviews, ...). Ideas?
Another idea for categorizing hotels with cities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to further explain your question so that we can be more help to you. If your intention is to just add a list of hotel names to your website then I don't know of any WordPress plugins for that, but you might want to check out Expedia's EAN http://developer.ean.com/

You need to sign for their affiliate program, which is very easy. You get immediate access to their hotel databases plus you can make availability/booking requests with several response options, including JSON, which is more convenient and lightweight than the (unfortunately) more widespread XML. This is something you will need to hire a developer to do.

If you want to allow clients/visitors to be able to book and search for hotels by just installing a plugin try https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-auto-hotel-finder/.